# Google Sheets how to use two formulas and get one result in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, weekday

I need to use two formulas in a cell and get only one result.

These are the formulas that I need to combine:

1. =WEEKDAY(M4) - in M4 there's the date (example: 20-October-2023)
2. =IFS(M11=2; "Lunedi"; M11=3; "Martedi")

Week days in Google Sheets are given by the formula in numbers (1,2,3 etc.). I don't need to see the numbers in any cell but directly the name of the day.

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Check the IFS function. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en

Comment: IFS doesn't allow me to use two formulas in one cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need two formula. Use `TEXT()` function. Try-

```
=TEXT(M4,"dddd")
```

[image]

Comment: That was easy! If the reference cell is empty the formula gives "Saturday" as result. How do I avoid this and get an empty cell? Thank you very much

Comment: Then try `=IF(M4="","",TEXT(M4,"dddd"))`.

Comment: It works, I had to change the , into ;
Thanks!

Comment: @Davidator It depends on language & regional settings.

Comment: yes, I understood it after a while :)